# Not sure how I can load all of this data into a static list, when the method is first called

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

Given the following method, how can I load all of this data (into memory) only once and when the first time this method is called?

NOTE: This method is from some ASP.NET MVC website.

```
private static IList<Foo> _foos;

public async Task<Foo> DoSomethingAsync(IDocumentSession documentSession,
    string name)
{
    if (_foos == null)
    {
        _foos = await LoadFoosFromDBAsync(documentSession);
    }

    var result = _foos.Where(x => x.Name == name).SingleOrDefault();

    return result;
}
```

I was initially thinking about trying to use a `Lazy<IList<Foo>>` or an `LazyAsync<IList<Foo>>` .. but because my method `LoadFoosFromDBAsync(..)` requires an instance of an `IDocumentSession`. I just can't figure out how to do all of this.

Comment: Do you mean store it in the `Session`? Or client side in the browser?

Comment: Where is `foo` suddenly coming from?

Comment: Not session and not application .. but a `static` variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable _foo will be null every time, because the Controller instance is not reused.

But what you can do, is to have a Singleton-type object in your MVC site, and use that instead. You would just use it like this:

```
var result = FooList.Instance.Data.Where(x => x.Name == name).SingleOrDefault();
```

(the `Instance` property is indicative of `FooList` being a Singleton).

Then you can implement FooList like so:

```
public sealed class FooList 
{
   private static volatile FooList instance;
   private static object syncRoot = new Object();

   private FooList ()
   {
        Data = .... // fill in how to fetch the data here, gets executed only once
   }

   public static FooList Instance
   {
      get 
      {
         if (instance == null) 
         {
            lock (syncRoot) 
            {
               if (instance == null) 
                  instance = new FooList ();
            }
         }

         return instance;
      }
   }

   public IList<Foo> Data { get; private set; }
}
```

Comment: Ok. so you're suggesting double-checked locking?

Comment: Yes, double-checked locking is a good mechanism for implementing a multithreaded Singleton.

Comment: 2 more Q's: 1) *The variable `_foo` will be null every time* :: Um, sure? `_foos` is defined as `private static IList<Foo> _foos;` A static .. so it's the same instance, despite having new class instances. 2) why `volatile`? How does that help, in this scenario?  For the rest - totally get all the rest :)

Comment: (2) The volatile thing is about synchronization. When you declare a variable volatile, it cannot be accessed before it is initialized because there will be no optimizations done on it by the compiler. So this ensures that even multiple threads will always read the correct value.

Comment: re: `_foos` AH! Sincerely sorry. I named it incorrectly in the method. Oooops! All fixed now. Cheers!!

Comment: @Pure.Krome, if this answers your question, please accept it as the answer. Thank you.